# Recompile main LaTeX document with latexmk when an associated m4 circuit macro file changed?

Tags: latexmk

I've a main LaTeX document with an associated `\input{file}` in it. This file is generated by the combination of the m4 macro processor and `dpic` (`m4 file.m4 | dpic > file.tex`) in order to take the .m4 file and output the `file.tex` that I need. Now if I change the `.m4` file I have to redo all the “intermediate” compilation. Is there an automated way to do this compilation if I run `latexmk`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I've figured out finally, so the basic idea is to set a custom dependency in latexmk. Here's the lines to add to ~/.latexmkrc file:

add_cus_dep('m4','tex',0,'mtotex');

sub mtotex{
system( "m4 '$_[0]'.m4 | dpic -g > '$_[0]'.tex" );
}

In the main latex file you can add your \input{name_file} command without worrying to compile the m4 circuit macro file “name_file.m4”.

You guys can improve my answer helping me to pass not only the dpic option -g but also other options.

Comment: Why don't you turn your comment into an answer (answer your own question)? and remove that [ANSWERED] from the title?

Comment: @karlkoeller Right!Actually I figured out before the time you have to wait to answer, but now I can modify.

Answer (score 2):

I've figured out finally, so the basic idea is to set a custom dependency in `latexmk`. Here's the lines to add to `~/.latexmkrc` file:

```
add_cus_dep('m4','tex',0,'mtotex');

sub mtotex{
system( "m4 '$_[0]'.m4 | dpic -g > '$_[0]'.tex" );
}
```

In the main LaTeX file you can add your `\input{name_file}` command without worrying to compile the m4 circuit macro file `name_file.m4`.